# Finding multiple instances of multiple words in Word using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am writing a VBA code to enter a user form and then transfer that data from the Excel sheet to an already existing Word document.
My Excel part is ok.

My document contains various words like Batch No, Manufacturing date, etc. each many times. I will have to find these words and insert Batch No and Manufacturing date from the user form every time they are found in the whole document.

Initially, I tried to find a single word in the whole document, but my sub routine can find only the first instance and is not finding similar words in rest of the document.

Please help

```
Sub Copy_data2()

    Dim my_filename As Variant
    Dim my_filenameword As Variant
    Dim objselection As Object

    'Word Variables
    Dim mres As String
    Dim oword As Object

    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

    Dim bfound As Boolean
    Dim rngDoc As Word.Range
    Dim rngSearch As Word.Range

    'Excel Variables
    Dim wkbk As Workbook
    Dim irow As Long
    Dim txtSl As String
    Dim txtBNo As String
    Dim txtPr As String
    Dim txtBS As String
    Dim txtMfD As String
    Dim txtExD As String

    Dim workinglocation As String
    Dim workingfilename As String
    Dim workingdir As String
    Dim ret As Boolean
    Dim VbRes As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Excel extract values
     '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    VbRes = MsgBox("Please select the Requisition sheet", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Select the requisition file")
    my_filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xls*")
    Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(my_filename)

    txtPr = FrmMaster.CmbProduct.Text
    txtBNo = FrmMaster.txtBatchNo
    txtBS = FrmMaster.txtBatchSize
    txtMfD = FrmMaster.txtMfgDate
    txtExD = FrmMaster.txtExpDate



    wkbk.Sheets("Requisition").Range("C9") = txtBNo
    wkbk.Sheets("Requisition").Range("G9") = txtBS
    wkbk.Sheets("Requisition").Range("C10") = txtMfD
    wkbk.Sheets("Requisition").Range("G10") = txtExD
    irow = [Counta(Database!A:A)]
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database").Cells(irow, 1) = txtSl
    Debug.Print txtSl

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'VB Word
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    mres = MsgBox("Select the Word BMR", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Select BMR")
    my_filenameword = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Word Files,*.doc*")

    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wdApp.Visible = True
    wdApp.Activate
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(my_filenameword)
    wdDoc.Activate


    With wdApp.Selection.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "BATCH SIZE"
        bfound = .Execute(Forward:=True)

            Do While bfound = True
            '.Move Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=4
             .Text = "BATCH SIZE"
             .Replacement.Text = "Size"
            Loop

    End With

    my_filenameword.Close True


    wkbk.Close True


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


 End Sub
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) • Please improve your question tell where exactly you got an issue in your code. Go through it step by step using F8 to investigate (and check your variable values) to find out where exactly it goes wrong.

Comment: I suggest you research the following topics: Bookmarks, REF fields; content controls, mapping content controls. These are two separate approaches for duplicating content throughout a Word document. There are lots of examples and discussions, both here and elsewhere on the Internet (as well as in books about using Word). Either of these would be the better approach than using FIND. But as far as your code goes: you need to repeat `bFound=Find.Execute` at the end of the loop. (And you can probably remove setting the text again, Word should remember that.)

Comment: For the example of Batch No.  Are you replacing the text Batch No with data from the form or inserting data from the form after the text Batch No.  Also does each occurence of Batch no have the same or different data.

Comment: The Batch No. will be same and will be added after the text Batch No

Comment: I cant loop through the whole document to find different instances of batch no and then inserting the batch no after the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should spend a few moments studying Find/Replace in Word. Even the macro recorder there would give you most of the code you need. Try:

```
  Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(my_filenameword, , False, False, , , , , , , , False)
  With wdDoc
    With .Range.Find
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Text = "BATCH SIZE"
      .Replacement.Text = "Size"
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    .Close True
  End With
```

As you can see, no looping is required - just a proper application of Find/Replace.

Comment: Thanks very much. But will i write the same for different words I have to search?

Comment: No, all you need do is add more sets of the '.Text = ', '.Replacement.Text = ' and '.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll' lines after the existing set..